# Error querying timestamp data using Python and Jaydebeapi

Tags: python, jaydebeapi, denodo

I'm receiving an error when trying to query data fields in Denodo that have a timestamp type. I'm using python 3.7.3 and the jaydebeapi.

Referencing the error I receive below, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' is indeed how the field is formatted, and '62690377-06-10 23:2' doesn't appear in the original data at all.

- If I convert the field to a string, the query works fine.
- Other users in my group are able to query the timestamp data without issues using the same version of Python and jaydebeapi and the code snippet below.

```py
query_complete = (" Select \"DATE\" FROM \"ABC\".\"simple_table\" ")

cursor.execute(query_complete)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
complete_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = list(zip(*cursor.description))[0]


ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-120011c28139> in <module>
     21 
     22 cursor.execute(query_complete)
---> 23 rows = cursor.fetchall()
     24 complete_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = list(zip(*cursor.description))[0])
     25 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jaydebeapi\__init__.py in fetchall(self)
    558         rows = []
    559         while True:
--> 560             row = self.fetchone()
    561             if row is None:
    562                 break

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jaydebeapi\__init__.py in fetchone(self)
    530             sqltype = self._meta.getColumnType(col)
    531             converter = self._converters.get(sqltype, _unknownSqlTypeConverter)
--> 532             v = converter(self._rs, col)
    533             row.append(v)
    534         return tuple(row)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jaydebeapi\__init__.py in _to_datetime(rs, col)
    582     if not java_val:
    583         return
--> 584     d = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(java_val)[:19], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    585     d = d.replace(microsecond=int(str(java_val.getNanos())[:6]))
    586     return str(d)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\_strptime.py in _strptime_datetime(cls, data_string, format)
    575     """Return a class cls instance based on the input string and the
    576     format string."""
--> 577     tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
    578     tzname, gmtoff = tt[-2:]
    579     args = tt[:6] + (fraction,)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\_strptime.py in _strptime(data_string, format)
    357     if not found:
    358         raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
--> 359                          (data_string, format))
    360     if len(data_string) != found.end():
    361         raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %

ValueError: time data '62690377-06-10 23:2' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`
```

I tried making a dummy data set to illustrate the issue. Sometimes as in this case, if the data set is small, I don't receive the value error but the output is garbled as can be seen when comparing the two sets of data below.

Query results when formatted as text in Denodo:

```py
timestamp_text
0   2017-04-06 12:23:56
1   1998-06-01 23:23:26
2   1990-04-28 15:23:56
3   2007-12-06 16:13:37
4   2010-08-27 17:30:09
```

Query results for same data when formatted as timestamp in Denodo:

```py
timestamp
0   1970-01-18 06:18:01.436000
1   1970-01-01 00:00:00
2   None
3   None
4   None
```

Comment: Hey Millie, its a little complicated to help here without access to the denodo logs or the exact output. But you say that others using the same code get correct data. Could you check if the jre that the jdbc driver uses is the same version for you and the others? if you are using the system wide jre you can check with "java -version" in a terminal. Could you also check the version of JPype1 module. I have seen different behavior with that as well.

Comment: Adding to @Millie Smith question, are you connecting to the same Denodo server as your coworkers or it is a different one?

Comment: Appreciate the replies! @Letimogo Here's my Java version:

java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)

I did have to roll back JPype to version 0.6.3 as there seems to be an issue with 0.7.0 but this issue was happening before the 0.7.0 release.

Comment: @Montecarlo thanks for your reply! Yes, same Denodo server and even querying the same data source. Two co-workers that installed everything six months ago are able to query timestamps without errors. Myself and a third co-worker who installed about a month ago are not. Additionally a fourth co-worker with a new install but running a different version of windows than the four others is able to query timestamps without error. Seems possible there's a "wrong" version of something but we have yet to figure out what. We've got the same versions of Python, Java, JPype1 and JayDeBeApi.

Comment: @MillieSmith The problem may be in the JDBC driver. The JDBC driver of Denodo 7 without updates has a problem returning datetime values. Copy the JDBC driver from the installation of the Denodo server you are connecting to.

Comment: @Montecarlo, I didn't have luck with the server copy of the driver. Is there anywhere to download a verified driver?

Comment: https://community.denodo.com/drivers/jdbc/32